# How to manually insert the data in SQL Server with following condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I set the `Identity Increment` with the primary key in one table, now I want to insert the data under GUI environment in SQL Server.

However, the primary key column is now read only and I am not able to edit it.

Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried this layout?  `INSERT INTO tbl (b, c, d) VALUES (x, y, z);` - Specifically ***not*** including the `id` column in any part of the statement?

Comment: Yes but I think I would like to manually input the data through GUI envirnment, Is that possible?

Comment: Like Dems said you don't need to include the `id` into your `INSERT` statement

Comment: If you have an identity column, why are you trying to insert into that column? That's contrary to what it's for. Could you describe the reason you have the identity column, and yet why you need to manually over-ride the identity nature of the column?  *[Also, do you mean in SQL Server Management Studio?]*

Comment: I mean I prefer to type the data into the table through GUI rather than SQL insert query.

Comment: @X.YangUK When you're entering the data through SSMS GUI, simply leave the PK field blank, and once you've finished entering the rest of your data, use the arrow key to move to a new line, and the identity will auto-generate a value for your PK.

Comment: @X.YangUK - Please be specific. When you say `GUI`, do you mean `SQL Server Management Studio`? If so, you can do that, you just don't touch the identity column - You simply populate the other fields and SQL Server populates the identity column for you. If you want to manually over-ride the identity column, ***why*** do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What GUI are you reffering to? (PHPAdmin, SQL Server Management Studio, other) In most cases if you enter the other columns and leave the `id` field open, the `id` will be autofilled in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the primary key field untouched and SQL Server will generate the data for you.